# 3剤3期クロスオーバーの分散分析：誤差をエクセルで算出したい

Tags: アルゴリズム, r, excel

3剤3期クロスオーバーの分散分析を、Rで実行しました（以下Rプログラム）。
この分散分析表の誤差「8.5089」をエクセルで算出したいのですが、結果が合いません。（誤差以外は検算できました）
以下に、エクセルの画像を添付しました。
どこの解釈が違うのか、どなたかアドバイスをお願いしてもよろしいでしょうか。
※データは「医薬品開発のための統計解析 第2部p.282」です。

※ [同じ質問を teratail でも質問中です](https://teratail.com/questions/286339) 。

```
group<-factor(c(c(rep(1,9)),c(rep(2,9)),c(rep(3,9))))
id<-factor(rep(1:9, each=3))
period<-factor(rep(c(1,2,3),9))
treat<-factor(c(rep(c(1,2,3),3),rep(c(3,1,2),3),rep(c(2,3,1),3)))
y<-c(7.2,6.6,7.9,8.4,8,7.1,9.2,10.7,8.8,7.9,8.2,9.2,7.8,9.7,10.1,6,9.4,10.2,5.6,6.8,9.2,6.4,6.2,8.6,7.3,7.3,9.5)
(anova<-anova(lm(y~group+treat+id*group+period)))

#          Df  Sum Sq Mean Sq F value   Pr(>F)   
#group      2  7.5822  3.7911  6.2377 0.011561 * 
#treat      2 10.4422  5.2211  8.5905 0.003678 **
#id         6 11.4978  1.9163  3.1530 0.035919 * 
#period     2 12.1756  6.0878 10.0165 0.001993 **
#Residuals 14  8.5089  0.6078

#Residualsの「8.5089」をエクセルで計算したい。
```

[image: エクセル]

各データの残差の2乗の合計（Residualsの平方和）が「8.5089」になるはずが「7.29」になっている。

#### 個人差の計算式

例えば、g1,id1の個人差-0.98
7.23-8.21=-0.98

#### 残差の計算式

例えば、g1,id1,period1の7.2に当たる残差-0.09
7.2-(8.27+(-0.98))=-0.09

※以下追記します。
2剤2期クロスオーバーの分散分析では同様の方法で算出しました。
3剤3期クロスオーバーの分散分析では同様の方法では算出できないのでしょうか。
[image: エクセル2]

Comment: エクセルでどのような計算式をつかっているのかの情報も無いと、回答が難しそうです。

Comment: コメントをありがとうございました。計算式を追記してみました。上記参考書の2×2クロスオーバーに記載してある計算式を、3×3クロスオーバーも同様に使用してみましたが、8.5089になりませんでした。他の平方和は検算できたので、入力ミス？ではないような気がするのですが。。

Comment: 赤い丸で囲まれているセル(7.29と表示されている

Comment: 7.29=3.35+3.11+0.83、残差2乗の合計です。分散分析表の誤差「8.5089」になると思って計算したのですが、7.29になっています。どのように計算したら8.5089になるのでしょうか。。

Comment: 残差の計算が違っているように見えます。たとえば、id1のperiod1の残差は0.078 = 7.2 - 0.089 (group1の効果) - 0.700 (treat1の効果) + 0.811 (period1の効果) + 0.978 (id1の効果) - 8.122 (全体平均) となるはずです。

Comment: コメントをありがとうございました！。できました！。8.5が出せて、とてもすっきりしました。treatでまとめた表も必要でした。。今回、ダミー変数の方法、分散の計算、ともに勉強になりました。どうもありがとうございました。まだまだ勉強が足りないと痛感しました。。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`lm()`部分の結果を見てみますと、多くの変数で回帰係数がNAとなっています。

```r
summary(lm(y ~ group + treat + id * group + period))
```

```
Call:
lm(formula = y ~ group + treat + id * group + period)

Residuals:
    Min      1Q  Median      3Q     Max 
-0.9111 -0.2167  0.0000  0.3278  1.0889 

Coefficients: (18 not defined because of singularities)
            Estimate Std. Error t value Pr(>|t|)    
(Intercept)   7.1222     0.5410  13.166 2.82e-09 ***
group2        1.3000     0.6365   2.042 0.060429 .  
group3        0.8000     0.6365   1.257 0.229394    
treat2       -0.5889     0.3675  -1.602 0.131386    
treat3       -1.5111     0.3675  -4.112 0.001058 ** 
id2           0.6000     0.6365   0.943 0.361871    
id3           2.3333     0.6365   3.666 0.002545 ** 
id4          -0.1000     0.6365  -0.157 0.877410    
id5           0.6667     0.6365   1.047 0.312695    
id6               NA         NA      NA       NA    
id7          -0.8333     0.6365  -1.309 0.211562    
id8          -0.9667     0.6365  -1.519 0.151113    
id9               NA         NA      NA       NA    
period2       0.7889     0.3675   2.147 0.049832 *  
period3       1.6444     0.3675   4.475 0.000524 ***
group2:id2        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id2        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id3        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id3        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id4        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id4        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id5        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id5        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id6        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id6        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id7        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id7        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id8        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id8        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group2:id9        NA         NA      NA       NA    
group3:id9        NA         NA      NA       NA    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

Residual standard error: 0.7796 on 14 degrees of freedom
Multiple R-squared:  0.8305,    Adjusted R-squared:  0.6853 
F-statistic: 5.717 on 12 and 14 DF,  p-value: 0.001433
```

NAとなる理由は、これらを説明変数として使用できないためです。たとえば、ダミー変数`group2:id2`や`group3:id2`などは、すべてのエントリーが0となります。また、`id6`と`group2:id6`は、どちらも16番目～18番目のエントリーが1、それ以外は0となるため、この2つの変数を判別することができません。

変数をダミー化し、上で回帰係数がNAとなっている変数を除いてから、Excelの分析ツールで回帰分析を実施したところ、分散分析表で残差の変動は`8.50888...`となっていました。

Excelでの再現手順は以下のようになります。（※これは純粋にご質問にあるR関数がやっているのと同じことをExcelで再現するための手順として紹介するもので、問題の解法として正しいかどうかという判断はしておりません。また、統計学的に正確でない表現が含まれるかもしれません。何卒ご承知ください。）

まず、各変数をダミー変数化します。ダミー変数化とは、カテゴリ変数を0と1の2値で表現される変数に変換することです。たとえば、`treat`をダミー変数化すると以下のようになります。

[image: ダミー変数化]

元の変数のカテゴリ数がN個の場合、1つを基準カテゴリーとし、残りのN-1個のカテゴリーをダミー変数化します。上の例では`treat1`が基準変数となり、すべての`treat`変数が0の場合、そのカテゴリは`treat1`ということになります。このようにすることで多重共線性を避けることができます。

同様に、`group`、`id`、`period`もそれぞれダミー変数化します。

また、このモデルには`id`と`group`の交互作用が含まれています。これは、`group_N`と`id_M`のすべての組み合わせを掛け合わせることで得られます。ここまでの作業で以下のような状態になっています。

[image: 中間結果1]

次に、不要な変数を削除します。たとえば、`group2:id2`などは、値がすべて0であり観測値間の違いを説明していないため不要です。また、`id4`と`group2:id4`などは、まったく同じ値であるため、1つは不要です。さらに、`id4`、`id5`、`id6`および`group2`を注意深く見ると、これらの`id`は`group2`のサブグループであり、どれか2つの`id`の値が0の場合、残り1つの`id`の値が1となることが自明であるため`id6`を削除します。同様に`id9`も消えます。

このようにして不要な変数を削除していった結果、残った変数は以下のようになります。先の`lm()`の出力結果で回帰係数がNAでない変数と一致していることをご確認ください。

[image: 中間結果2]

このデータに対して、Excel標準の「分析ツール」アドインで回帰分析を実行します。するとご覧のとおり、残差の変動がRの出力と同じ値になることを確認できます。

[image: 最終結果]

Comment: ご回答をありがとうございます！。とにかく回答がついたことに嬉しく思います。で、すみません、、恥ずかしながら勉強不足でお伺いさせていただきます。変数をダミー化し、回帰係数がNAとなっている変数を除いてから…というのは、具体的にはどのようにしたらよいのでしょうか。私の作成したエクセルの表では簡単に算出できない感じでしょうか。もしよろしければもう少しご助言ください。。

Comment: 説明が不足しておりましたので、回答に追記しました。

Comment: 追記をどうもありがとうございました!。ご丁寧にUPしていただき、大変感謝しております。ご提示の方法を確認させていただいたところ、同様の表（及び8.50..）を確認できました。どうもありがとうございました。やっぱり、私の作成したエクセルの表では、どこかの誤差が入っていないようです。Cross Validatedでも同様の質問をしていて、次のようなコメントをもらっていましたが、よくわかりませんでした。。hey your model is over determined. you do not have the information to estimate the interaction terms. do table(group,id) and you can see that for example id 1-3 only exist in group 1   https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/484857/how-to-calculate-residuals-s-sum-sq-of-33-crossover-design-analysis

Comment: "overdetermined"という用語があるのですね。勉強になります。groupとidの交互作用項をモデルに含んでいますが、実際のデータではid 1-3はgroup1の中にしか存在しません。id1 = 1のときは常にgroup1 = 1、id1 = 0のときは常にgroup1 = 0となり、交互作用項group1 * id1 = id1となってしまいます（他のすべてのidとgroupの組み合わせについても同様）。そのため交互作用項をモデルに追加しても無意味です。このようにほかの説明変数がすでに持っている情報と同じ情報しか持っていない説明変数をモデルに加えることは過剰(overdetermined)だ、というようなことを言っているのだと思います。

Comment: コメントをありがとうございました！。1日考えてみましたが、やっぱり、なかなかイメージがわきません。。海外の方も、ご提示のようなダミー変数を使った場合と同様のことを言っているのかなぁ…と漠然としています。。（ついていけていない…）。そもそもは、左記の資料を実装したかっただけでした。https://scientist-press.com/wp/wp-content/uploads/2019/07/seminar8.pdf。2剤2期はできていて、3剤3期も同様な方法で…と書かれていたので、すんなりできるかと思いましたが。。